# C: Value of variable changing without re-assignment

Tags: c, graph-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I am implementing Kruskal's algorithm.

After I call graph() in the following code, the value of nodes change. I'm not quite sure why -- if anyone could clear this up I would greatly appreciate it. I'm not accessing the value of nodes from within graph, and both nodes & edges, the array being accessed, are allocated outside of the stack!

```
struct node {
  int parent, rank;
};
typedef struct node node;

struct edge {
  int fromvertex, tovertex;
  float weight;
};
typedef struct edge edge;

node* nodes;
edge* edges;

typedef enum {Unvisited, Visited} vertexstate;

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  void getcount(int*, int*);
  void graph(int, int);
  void makeset(int);
  int hasspantree(int, int, int);
  void kruskal(int, int);
  int printmcst(int);
  int nodecount, edgecount, i, totalcost=0;
  getcount(&nodecount, &edgecount);
  for (i = 1; i <= nodecount; i++)
    makeset(i);
  printf("%d \t %d\n", nodes[6].parent, nodes[6].rank );
  graph(nodecount, edgecount);
  printf("%d \t %d\n", nodes[6].parent, nodes[6].rank );
  printf("Has a spanning tree?");
  if(hasspantree(1, nodecount, edgecount)) {
    printf("\t Yes.\n");
    kruskal(nodecount, edgecount);
    printf("MCST found:\n\n");
    totalcost = printmcst(nodecount);
    printf("\nCost: %d", totalcost);
  }
  else {
    printf("No.");
    exit(0);
  }
  return 0;
}

void graph(int nodecount, int edgecount)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < edgecount; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &edges[i].fromvertex);
    scanf("%d", &edges[i].tovertex);
    scanf("%f", &edges[i].weight);
  }
}

void getcount(int *nodecount, int *edgecount)
{
  scanf("%d", nodecount);
  scanf("%d", edgecount);
  nodes = malloc(*nodecount * sizeof(node));
  edges = malloc(*edgecount * sizeof(edge));
}

void makeset(int x)
{
  nodes[x].parent = x;
  nodes[x].rank = 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you do in `makeset`?

Comment: @unxnut in makeset, I make singleton sets of all the nodes. I've edited my original post to include makeset().

Comment: all of the function prototypes need to be outside/before the main() function, so the compiler knows what to expect for declarations and calls to those functions.  Otherwise, with the prototypes within the main() function, those prototypes are 'out of scope' and therefore do not exist beyond the limits of the main() function.

Comment: @user3629249 There *are* no calls to those functions outside `main`. Putting declarations inside a function is perfectly OK, albeit unusual.

Comment: in this function: void graph(int nodecount, int edgecount) it would be a very good idea to prefix each scanf() with a printf() letting the user know what they are expected to enter.

Comment: each call to scanf() should include a check of the return parameter to assure that the format conversion was successful for each parameter of the call.

Comment: each call to malloc() should include a check of the return parameter to assure that the memory was successfully allocated.

Comment: at the end of main(), all the malloc'd areas need to be passed to free() otherwise a memory leak/resource loss occurs

Comment: these two lines: for (i = 1; i <= nodecount; i++)
    makeset(i); will result in undefined behaviour because the index for a C array is 0...<arraysize, not 1...arraysize. I.E. the last access will be beyond the end of the array.  this can result in several kinds of subtle errors, even a seg fault event.

Comment: in this function: void graph(int nodecount, int edgecount) the nodecount variable is never referenced.  the compiler should/will output a warning/error over this.

Comment: where is this function:void kruskal(int, int); defined/implemented?

Comment: there seems to be missing two #include statements, one for stdlib.h and one for stdio.h.  Perhaps a third #include for kruskal(), in which case the function prototype should not be anywhere in the code, but rather in the kruskal.h header file.

Comment: the sub functions that call scanf or malloc could fail.  they need to have a return code that can be checked in the main() function, so (if needed) the malloc'd areas can be free'd and the program can gracefully exit

Comment: all the scanf() format parameters should include a leading ' ' so that leading white space (including newlines) will be skipped over.

Comment: regarding this line: printf("No.");  the format parameter should have a trailing '\n' to assure the line will actually be output before the program is exited.

Comment: @user3629249 Regarding Function Prototypes: Old-school (pre-ANSI) C style recommends having function declarations inside of methods as to avoid having global function declarations. This is the same school of thought that recommends against global variables.

Comment: this line: typedef enum {Unvisited, Visited} vertexstate; describes a typedef that is not used.  the compiler should have raised a warning/error.  I.E. since it is not used, it should be removed.

Comment: this line: if(hasspantree(1, nodecount, edgecount)) { references the function hasspantree() however, there is not declaration of the function nor a #include statement that would indicate the function is defined in another file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one obvious error is accessing the nodes array starting at index 1 instead of 0 and this would cause buffer overrun when you access the last element

```
 for (i = 1; i <= nodecount; i++)  <-- here i should start at 0 and access only up to nodecount-1
    makeset(i);
```

Comment: Exactly. And the overrun or under run may affect the variables stored next to it on the stack

Comment: Went through and scanned for off-by-one errors, and those were the root of all of my problems. Thanks, RADAR!